# Drop down list in access form and displaying the data from the next column

Tags: ms-access

Please help me with the following topic.
I'm having a hard time inserting a form in which i need to select from a drop down list the name of the project and below to display the data from the ProdFinit column.

I've tried using combo but i'm new to Access and i thing i'm missing something.

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path using a combobox. Look at the format tab on the design properties for your combobox. Here I have a form where the user inputs the zip code, but I also want the user to identify the city and state at the same time. My column count is 3 and I chose how wide to make those columns on the next line down. Beware what column to bind it to on the datatab of the properties box. I find binding it to column 1 is easiest.

[ComboBox Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tCwHN.png)
[Zipcode Combobox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2u0vm.png)